# Update browser's cache after applying Dom Manipulation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, dom

I have a webpage that will list participants of a course based on search parameters in a webform. For each participant there's a status and an action button, that will open a popup window, to update the status of a participant....something like this:

- mr nice guy - active [edit]
- superman - pending [edit]
- batwoman - active [edit]
- queen elizabeth - closed [edit]

If the status of a participant has been changed in the popup window, the status is updated in the list without doing a postback - this is done by manipukating the dom via jquery.

Now the issue is, that if I click on a link to another page, and then use the back-button, then the browser will show the original version of the list *without* the most recent status changes. The list can be refreshed by pressing F5 or re-submitting the search form, but I would like to avoid having to do that.

So, the question is whether I can instruct the browser to refresh/update the cached version of the current page somehow? (as opposed to invalidating the cache or reloading the page)

Ideally I would like something like the local storage API to do a "sessionStorage.refresh" or "document.updateCache" or something along those lines.